# When iterating through a list, how to skip a certain element

Tags: python

I'm currently using

```
for i in list:
    if len(set(list(map(lambda x: x[0], i)))) == 1:
```

when iterating through two lists:

```
list = [['2C', '2S', '2H'], ['7H', '7C', 'AH']]
```

and

```
list = [['4H', '4S', 'AC', '4C'],['7H', '7C', 'AH', 'AC']]
```

What I'm doing here is to check if every element in each list starts with the same character only within that list. I was wondering if there is a way to skip the elements that starts with 'A' when iterating and only care about those with none 'A' as a starting character.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it redefines the built-in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension instead of `map`. Then you can skip elements.

```
if len(set([x[0] for x in i if x[0] != 'A')) == 1:
```

Comment: wouldn''t you need a nested comprehension to check all elements in each sublist? Otherwise aren't you only checking the first element in each sublist?

Comment: `i` is a sublist due to `for i in list:`

Answer (score 1):

```py
for element in list:
    if element.startswith("A"):
        continue
    # do something with the elements
```